# Compile .kit files outside of Codekit

Tags: codekit

Codekit offers the ability to split static HTML files into designated partials using the include function and .kit files. More info: http://incident57.com/codekit/kit.php

The question is.. Using this file type works great for users that have CodeKit. But makes it so that anyone making HTML changes also needs a CodeKit license.

Is there anyway to compile these .kit partials without or outside of Codekit?

Answer (score 2):

Even when the question is one year old:

- For Windows User and Mac(CodeKit alternative App):

  - http://alphapixels.com/prepros/
- For Linux, Mac and Windows (CLI):

  - **Grunt:**
    https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-codekit
  - **Gulp:**
    https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-codekit

Answer (score 1):

I've spoken with Bryan (creator of CodeKit) and as of now there is no other way of compiling outside of CodeKit. There is also no server-side compiler (like with LESS) that can compile. So my advice would be to make no project rely on Kit unless you are sure it is going to someone who has CodeKit.