# How can I separate an html page into parts without server script support?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, nginx, frontend

I want to separate an html page into head, header, footer sort of stuff like that. And include them as I create a new page so that I won't have to update all pages if I change something in header or other parts of the included ones.

The problem is that I can do that easily with php support but the current server nginx(actually I don't really know what that means as a front-end dev) doesn't have that and won't do in the future. How can I accomplish that with pure html or with a little help of nginx?

Comment: Try SSI. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript includes.

For example if you were using jQuery…

page1.html

```
<div id="head"></div>
<script src="head.js"></script>
```

head.js

```
$('#head').html('<html goes here>');
```

Comment: By head, I mean something like "<html><head></head>" which has js files like jquery included if jquery is not included in the html in the first place, then how could the head.js even work? I have to say this is not an elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t mind compiling before uploading you could use .kit files. 
https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#kit

And it’s not just for mac users…
[Compile .kit files outside of Codekit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708051/compile-kit-files-outside-of-codekit)